# How to show the selected plan value in a text box in vue js html?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

My json data is as follows

```
{"status": true, "plans": [{"planId": 1, "name": "Baic", "cost": 500.0, "validity": 365}, {"planId": 3, "name": "free", "cost": 0.0, "validity": 999}, {"planId": 4, "name": "Premium", "cost": 500.0, "validity": 500}, {"planId": 5, "name": "Super Premium", "cost": 750.0, "validity": 600}, {"planId": 6, "name": "New", "cost": 600.0, "validity": 180}]}
```

I need to select a particular category from the above list and display the corresponding cost of the category in a text box and i need to able to edit the value. How acan I able to obtain the same.

Currently my html code is

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label>Plan <small>(select your plan)</small></label>
     <select id="bas" class="selectpicker"  data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="begins" title="Select Plan" v-model="plan" name="plan" ref="plan" required="required">
   <option v-for="post in plansb" v-bind:value="post.planId" v-if="plansb.indexOf(post) > 0">{{post.name}} (Rs.{{post.cost}})</option>
            </select>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
     <label>Plan Amount <small>(required)</small></label>
<input name="plan_amt" type="text" class="form-control" id="plan_amt" placeholder="Plan Amount" v-model="plan_amt" />
        </div>
```

In the Plan Amount text-box I need to display the cost of which category is selected from the above selection. Now I need to enter the amount. IF is selected planId = 1, I need to display 500 in the text-box. Also i need to edit those value and send as as ajax request.

How can I able to get the result as such.

My vue js code is

```
vBox = new Vue({
el: "#vBox",
  data: {
        plansb: [],
        plan: '',
        plan_amt: '',
    },
     mounted: function() {
       var vm = this;
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/alpha/get/plan/",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(e) {
               if (e.status == 1) { 
             vm.plansb = e.plans;
            }
            },
        });
       },
      methods: {
         handelSubmit: function(e) {
               var vm = this;
               data = {};
               data['plan'] = this.plan;
               data['plan_amt'] = this.plan_amt;

                $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/alpha/add/post/',
                  data: data,
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function(e) {
                  if (e.status)
                  {

                    $("#alertModal").modal('show');
                  $(".alert").removeClass("hidden").html("Your data has been successfully recorded");

                    vm.pid=e.pid;
                    console.log(vm.pid);

                }
                  else {
                    vm.response = e;

                   alert("Registration Failed") 
                  }
              }
                });
                return false;
              },
```

Can anybody please help me to obtain the result. Based on the selection of plans from the select, I need to update the values in the text box. Please help me to have a result.

Comment: Is it `plans` or `plansb`. Show us the data options.

Comment: ok sir,, i will update my vue js

Comment: sir.. i have saved the json data in plasb[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add change event of list and get the planid of palns, and according to planid get cost of it and assign it to cost(text-box) model where u want to show change plan cost

Comment: can you please help me to have a solution

Comment: add an example to your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921342/working-hours-selection i am also facing a situation like this.. can you provide a solution